# Is there a way to deploy a python desktop app in an organization?

Tags: python, tkinter, installation, deployment, desktop-application

So the company I work for is very restrictive in giving software out to a large number of employees. I was asked to create a small desktop app that takes in certain parameters from the user and queries an internal database and outputs a csv with the results. I made this app in python. However, the organization is being stringent and not allowing me to load python onto everyone's laptops. **Is there anyway to make this app usable by everyone without having python downloaded onto their computers?**

As of right now, the app is hosted in an application and database server only accessible by my team and IT. We have access to docker but I'm not too experienced with that so I'm not sure if that would help.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We expect you to do appropriate research, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.  Your post is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Make the py file to an exe and send that to employees

Comment: I think creating a PWA (Progressive Web Application) is more suitable in your case.  For Python, take a look on [Flask PWA](https://www.flaskpwa.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You could run your app through [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/). That creates a .exe installer file. Your network overlords may, or may not, allow you to distribute that installer to employees. You should ask before you do any more work in that direction. Big orgs are really reluctant to deploy desktop apps widely. Because cybercreeps and security compliance.

You could rework it into a web app that people can use via their web browsers. Downloading .csv files from web apps is simple. And, hitting your database from the server running the web app is plenty more secure and scalable than hitting it from lots of desktop apps.  And, web apps are easier to update when needed.

There are a whole mess of web app frameworks for python available. Ask whether your org has chosen a particular one. If so, use it: you'll have programming and deployment expertise to draw on as you finish this project.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Just I was the only one hired with a python background so I'm kinda the expert there even though I'm a new grad. I'll look into making it a web app and requisite libraries. Idk why they wanted a python dev but not support python apps... Thanks though!

Comment: Be patient. Large orgs have "separation of responsibility", meaning the right hand has no idea what the left hand is doing until years later. Talk to your own boss about how to manage your org to get your stuff released. The politics are usually a bigger challenge than the tech